# Can I revert back to the old profile on the communities that adopted the new profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

No missing features I just prefer the old one.Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Once all sites have been converted to the new profile, the old one will be retired for good.

Comment: That is very sad news :(

Comment: @user1298069 Change is always jarring, but before too long, you wont even remember it used to be another way... and then you'll see an old screenshot or something and say *yuck, pooey, how did we ever get by with that gawd-awful design.*